# Adding object to object array

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
struct Calculators
{
    var calculators: [Calculator]?
    var activeCalculator: Int = -1
    var activeSummary: Bool = false
    var activeProfits: Bool = false

public mutating func addCalc(calc: Calculator){
        self.calculators?.append(calc)
    }
}

struct Calculator
{
    var priceSum: Float = 0
    var weightSum: Float = 0
    var pricePerMix: Float = 0

    var pricePerPortion: Decimal?
    var portionDivider: Float?
    var nettoPortionCost: Float?
    var profitPerPortion: Float?
    var pricePerKgAfterPrepare: Float?
    var weightPerPortionInGrams: Float? 
    var concept : PromoConcepts?

    let createTime: Double
    var products : [CountedProduct]?

    init() {
        createTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
    }
}
```

When I'm trying add new object:

```
var activeCalculators = Calculators()
    let calculator = Calculator()
    activeCalculators.addCalc(calc: calculator)
```

to object array ([Calculator]?).

The app does not add this (not working).

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Calculators
{
    var calculators: [Calculator]?
    var activeCalculator: Int = -1
    var activeSummary: Bool = false
    var activeProfits: Bool = false

    public mutating func addCalc(calc: Calculator){
        if calculators == nil {
             self.calculators = []
        }
        self.calculators?.append(calc)
    }
}
```

Just initialize calculators inside the addCalc func, if you still want to have calculators as a nullable var.
If this isn't essential for you, go for the solution of Sh_Khan

Answer (score 3):

I guess you forgot to create the array:

```
var calculators: [Calculator]? = [Calculator]()
```

Comment: I have array in class Calculators: var calculators: [Calculator]?

Comment: @traff you have not initialized it

Comment: @traff, This is declaring it, not creating it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to init it like this

```
activeCalculators = [Calculator]()
```

//

```
struct Calculators
{
    var calculators = [Calculator]()
    var activeCalculator: Int = -1
    var activeSummary: Bool = false
    var activeProfits: Bool = false

public mutating func addCalc(calc: Calculator){
        self.calculators.append(calc)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot paste it. I have this: var activeCalculators = Calculators()

Answer (score 1):

Your default initialization method didn't not create a Calculator Array.
So when you initialize it like this
`var activeCalculators = Calculators(calculators: nil, ...`

The `add` could not be done, because the `calculators` is actually nil.

You should initialize it like this
 `var activeCalculators = Calculators(calculators: [Calculator()], ...`
Or do something to make it not nil.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to insert object into uninitiazed array.

You have two Options:

1.Create & Initialise array

```
var calculators = [Calculator]()
```

2.Initialise array before adding object to it.

```
var activeCalculators = Calculators()
activeCalculators.calculators = [Calculator]()
let calculator = Calculator()
activeCalculators.addCalc(calc: calculator)
```